# Accessing multidimensional Array, Laravel

Tags: laravel, multidimensional-array

I am getting error `Illegal offset type` on next segment of code (the condition within foreach method is causing an error):

```
 $filter = [];
 foreach ($properties[array_keys($properties)] as $prop)
     array_add($filter, array_keys($prop), $prop->id);
```

And this is how [$properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGMhs.png) array look like. What I am trying to do is adding elements of array inside `$properties` into another array (etc. `$filter['1'] = $properties['1']`). The problem is that I never know how many elements (arrays) are going to be inside `$properties` and also I don't know what values are they going to be, so I can access them.

If there is an easier way to achieve this, feel free to write it down.

P.S.
`id` is element of array in `$properties`.

Comment: Are you trying to copy the whole `$properties` variable into `$filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not seem like valid code to me. `array_keys` [returns a new array](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php) which you are trying to use as a key to get a value out of `$properties` inside your `foreach`

Try this:

```
$filter = [];
foreach ($properties as $key => $prop)
    $filter[$key] = $prop['id'];
```

#### EDIT

If you only want the ids, i would recommend to use `array_pluck`.
It's one of [laravels amazing helper functions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-pluck)

It would then look like this:

```
$filter = array_pluck($properties, 'id');
```

Comment: Actually, you are right about `array_keys` method. I am newbie at this, so it was my mistake.
About code you have written in this answer, I am getting next error `Trying to get property of non-object`. This is probably because elements of $properties are not objects, but arrays?
Also, I do not need whole `$properties` into `$filter`, I just need `$properties[$key]->id` (I know this is probably not the right syntax, but I guess you can understand what I am talking about).

Comment: Yepp, your guess should be right. there are no objects inside your properties array. See edit. PS. remember to accept the answer, if it solves your problem.